# html, body tags not working from external file

Tags: css

Why this works when in html file between  but not when in my external css file?
I have to add that this external file also has lots of other class and id selectors and most of them work externally but some don't. All work fine in a html though...

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("background.png");
}
```

Comment: Do you have other CSS files that you load after this one? If they also try to set these styles, the last one wins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have to add external css file in between Head.
>
> In that External file us !important. so it will apply to all pages
>
> link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css"

I know all this of course, I found the problem it was a extra character I missed and some of the CSS wasn't used...

Answer (score 0):

When you work with external css, you must load te external CSS file.

Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="theme.css">
```

Where `theme.css` is the path to your css file.

PS: You must put this between your `<head>` and `</head>` tags.

**EDIT**

Be sure you have the `<!DOCTYPE html>` (at the beginning of file) and all necessary tags declared.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add external css file in between Head.

In that External file us !important. so it will apply to all pages

```
html, body
{
height:100% !important;
}
```

Otherwise call the class for body tag which file you have want bg image

in HTML File

```
<body class="bg">
..
</body>
```

CSS file

```
.bg
{
background:url(imgurl); // if you want use !important
}
```